# How to debug this Node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I am trying to execute below code but I am not getting expected output.

```
recursive(prodURL, function(err, files) {
    targetDeviceUpdate("updatedPath");   
});
function targetDeviceUpdate(sourceImages, updatedPath) {
    console.log("1 " + updatedPath);
    recursive(prodURL + "/device", function(err, files) {
        console.log("3 " + updatedPath);
    });
}
```

Expected output:

> 1 updatedPath
>
> 3 updatedPath
>
> 1 updatedPath
>
> 3 updatedPath

Actual output:

> 1 updatedPath
>
> 1 updatedPath
>
> 3 updatedPath
>
> 3 updatedPath

Comment: Can you provide your "recursive" function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what functionality do you want?  Your code does exactly as you say because It calls the function [itself] again from the second line.  Then finally gets to the rest.

If you want them interwoven, you'll have to call them sequentially within the function, not recursively.  Recursive actions tail-up and end up spiraling, which creates this duplication you see.

Please try and use descriptive names (longer is actually better) and although CamelCase is nice, I prefer hyphens-for-naming-variables, however, since javascript does not interpret hyphens as anything but minus signs, you can use underscores_to_name_your_variables_cleanly.

```
the_method_thatinvokes_target_device_update(prodURL, function(err, files) {
  target_device_update("updatedPath");   
});

function target_device_update(sourceImages, updated_path) {
  console.log("Here is the first line: " + updated_path);
  the_method_that_invokes_target_device_update(prodURL + "/device", function(err, files) {
    //invoking this function will naturally call the first line again before reaching the rest of the code.

    //and this 'callback' or 'remainder' code gets called only after, and twice at that.
    console.log("3 " + updated_path);

  });
}
```

To get the effect you want, you don't need recursion.  Just call the changes sequentially.  What specifically are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Both recursive function have different use. I am using more that 1500 files each time.

Comment: @golekunal88 Do the different work in different functions